# Solution for a SDE for a Bond found in Bugard & Kjaer

Tags: stochastic-calculus, jump-diffusion, default

I'm going over the paper *-Partial Differential Equation Representation of Derivatives with Bilateral Counterparty Risk and Funding Costs-* from Burgard and Kjaer.   There the following SDE is given for a defaultable bond:
$$ dP(t) = r(t)P(t)dt - P(t)dJ(t), $$
where $r(t)$ is an adapted process, and $J(t)$ is a jump process that changes from zero to one on default of the bond issuer.

I'm trying to solve this SDE by finding a closed form formula for $P(t)$, where I'm following the theory given in Steven Shreve's book: *-Stochastic Calculus for Finance, Continuous-Time Models-* (Chapter 11).  I'm attempting to use Ito's formula for jumps, but I'm stuck.  Any hints on how to proceed to formally get $P(t)$ from the SDE?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: As an aside, while the authors claim these are the dynamics for a defaultable bond, if we assume a stochastic rate $r(t)$, they are probably inconsistent as there should be contribution from the rate's volatility, vanishing as we approach the bond's maturity. This is probably best viewed as continuously rolled-over commercial paper from the issuer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'll assume
$$ J_t = \sum_{i=1}^{N_t} Z_i$$ be a [compound Poisson process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compound_Poisson_process), with $(T_n)_{n\geq 1}$ being the jump times for Poisson process $(N_t)_{t\geq 0}$ and $(Z_i)_{i\geq 1}$ sequence of i.i.d. variables independent of $(N_t)_{t\geq 0}$.

For SDE

$$ dP_t = P_{t^-} dJ_t $$

we notice that at jump times we have

$$  dP_{T_i} = P_{T_i} - P_{T_i^-} = Z_{i} P_{T_i^-} $$

so

$$ P_{T_i} =  (1+Z_i) P_{T_i^-} $$

From here we can conclude that:

$$ P_t = P_0 \prod _{i=1}^{N_t} (1+Z_i) $$

Adding drift

$$ dP_t = r_t P_t dt + P_{t^-} dJ_t $$

gives

$$ P_t = P_0 \mathrm{e}^{\int_0^t r_s ds}\prod _{i=1}^{N_t} (1+Z_i) $$

as between jump times $P_t$ evolves as $ r_t P_t dt$ and gets multiplied by $1+Z_{i}$ at $T_{i}$, starting with

$$ P_t = P_0 \mathrm{e}^{\int_0^t r_s ds} $$

for $t\in [0,T_1)$.

Comment: Note that in Burgard & Kjaer’s paper, $J_t$ is used to model counterparty default, hence we set $Z_1=-1$. Then, as soon as $J_t$ jumps for the first time, the product becomes null, so that we can write: $$P_t=P_0e^{\int_0^tr_sds}1_{\{N_t=0\}}=P_0e^{\int_0^tr_sds}1_{\{t<T_1\}}.$$

Comment: @DaneelOlivaw Thank you. Could you please add a separate, complementary answer addressing default risk? It's well worth it to clearly make that distinction. I recited the general case, but you are are really answering OP's question :).

Comment: Thank you very much.  Indeed your answer, together with @DaneelOlivaw, helped me solve this.

Answer (score 2):

As a complement to @ir7’s comprehensive derivation, in the case of Burgard and Kjaer’s the jump process $J_t$ models the default of the issuer. You specialize the process by setting $Z_1=-1$, while the values of $\{Z_i:i\geq2\}$ are irrelevant. You then notice that as soon as the process jumps once, the product of jump sizes becomes null. We therefore have:
$$ P_t =
P_0e^{\int_0^tr_sds}\mathbf{1}_{\{N_t=0\}} =
P_0e^{\int_0^tr_sds}\mathbf{1}_{\{t<T_1\}}
$$
where $T_1$ is the default time of the issuer.

Comment: Thanks!  Indeed this is the partiicular case I'm looking for.  Cheers.